# How to save and validate objects correctly using django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm learning `django rest framework` and I have found problems validating and saving objects correctly.

When I receive a request to create a dialog, I first need to create a dialog, and then to add participants to it.

This is code of `Dialog` model:

```
class DialogManager(models.Manager):
    def create_dialog(self, name):
        max_length(name, 30)
        dialog = self.model(name=name)
        dialog.save()
        return dialog


class Dialog(models.Model):
    name                = models.CharField(null=False)
    created_at          = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    objects = DialogManager()
```

my `Participant` model:

```
class ParticipantManager(models.Manager):
    def create_participant(self, dialog, user, role="user"):
        if role not in ["user", "admin"]:
            raise ValueError('Incorrect role for the user')

        max_length(role, 30)

        participant = Participant(role=role, dialog=dialog, user=user)
        participant.save()
        return participant


class Participant(models.Model):
    role                = models.CharField(null=False)
    dialog              = models.ForeignKey(Dialog, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user                = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    objects = ParticipantManager()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('dialog', 'user',)
```

and `Dialog` set:

```
class DialogSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Dialog.objects.all()

    serializer_class = DialogSerializer
    pagination_class = DialogSetPagination

    def create(self, request):
        data = request.data
        users = CustomUser.objects.filter(pk__in=data['ids'])
        dialog_serializer = DialogSerializer(data=data)
        if not dialog_serializer.is_valid():
            return Response(dialog_serializer.errors, status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        with transaction.atomic():
            dialog = dialog_serializer.save()
            i = 0
            for user in users:
                participant_serializer = ParticipantSerializer(data={'dialog': dialog.pk, 'user': user.pk, 'role': 'user'})
                if not participant_serializer.is_valid():
                    return Response(participant_serializer.errors, status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
                i += 1

        return Response(dialog, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

The problem is that I can save an object of `Dialog`, and then validate `participants` objects and they will be invalid. And I will need to do rollback. Can I change the process of creating `dialog` and `participants` objects without using transactions? And this led me to many other questions.

1. I was told double validations in models and serializers wasn't a good idea. As I understand it is better to store all validations in the model, but in the serializers to add only validations not related to the database?
2. So, I add custom `create` methods to both models `Dialog` and `Participant`. But in this case it turns out that the creation method also deals with validations and I know there is no validation method in `django` models that is called before the creation of the object. So,  where to determine the validations?
3. And there is another problem, `create` method involves save an object, as I understand. I need to put saved `dialog` object into `participants` objects, but I will need to rollback changes if `participants` objects will be invalid. Shall the creation method save the object?
4. When I don't put `role` key to `Participant` serializer in my `DialogSet` and then call `.is_valid()`, it calls `validate` in serializer, it checks if role is specified. So, I again have double validations, in `validate` method and in `create_participant`. But I want to check if `role` specified by calling model validation method in my serializer and then call `create_participant` to save an object. Can I do it?

To summarize, I want to get something like this:

```
class ParticipantSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Participant
        fields = '__all__'

    def validate(self, data):
        data = ParticipantManager.validate(**data)
        return data


    def create(self, validated_data):
        role = validated_data['role']
        user = validated_data['user']
        dialog = validated_data['role']
        participant = Participant.objects.create_participant(dialog, user, role)
        return participant

class ParticipantManager(models.Manager):

    def create_participant(self, dialog, user, role):
        participant = Participant(dialog=dialog, user=user, role=role)
        participant.save()
        return participant

    def validate(self, data):
        ## validate data
        return data
```

If this code is not correct, please tell me how to do it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I have read about clean() in Django and it solved my problem. The question is closed.